# Black area on top window when creating screenshot with Robot createScreenShot

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I'm taking screenshots of a Java Web Start application and in a case of some windows on Linux, strange black area appears on the right side of the windows.

[Here's a link to example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTEvG.png)

I'm using Xvnc, Gnome on following screenshot but this problem appears as well with TWM. Here is a code which creates the image:

```
Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
File file = new File(dir, "zrzut" + format.format( new Date() ) + ".png");
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rectangle);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
```

When I'm connecting with Xvnc thru VNC session, everything seems to be looking fine in VNC client window. I have problems with this Java code, but also screenshots created with xwd are also affected by this problem. I've tried xrefresh, but it's not helping.

Comment: are you playing some game there? what is supposed to be in the black area?

Comment: The rest of the window ;) It's a part of automated testing of this app using Robot Framework.

Comment: there might be some game type window there but since you exclude its my guess